# Logic OR / AND term evaluation order in Ruby

Tags: ruby, operators, boolean-logic

In Ruby, for the binary logic operators AND and OR, what's the order of evaluation of the terms, i.e., in an instruction like

```
if bool1 || bool2
```

which boolean value is checked first? Is it left to right as intuition suggests? Do both need to be checked if the first one is true already (or false in the case of an AND)?

This is of particular interest when 2 conditions need to be checked, but we're only really interested in verifying the second one (e.g., a more resource consuming check) provided the first one fails.

Searching for this info often leads to operator precedence tables and specially operator associativity, but as you can see that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ruby uses Short-circuit evaluation, so it evaluates the first argument to decide if it should continue with the second one.

Comment: Rubyists often write code that depends on left-to-right, short-circuit evaluation, such as `result = obj.is_a?(Hash) && obj[k]`.

Comment: It might be worth noting that when using `|` instead of `||`, both sides are being evaluated. See [`TrueClass#|`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/TrueClass.html#7C-method) for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby community commonly used is `short-circuit` evaluation which is `&&` stands for `AND`, `||` stands for `OR`

> It means in a conditional statement with two conditions the second condition is evaluated only when the first condition is not enough to determine the value of expression

so let's take an example for `&&`, `||`

```rb
def a
  puts 'a method'
  false
end

def b
  'b method'
   true
end

a && b
# 'a method'
# => false
```

b is never evaluated

```rb
def a
  puts 'a method'
  true
end

def b
  'b method'
   false
end

a || b
# 'a method'
# => true
```

b is also never evaluated

there is another construction `and`, `or` (lowercased)

> The and and or keywords serve the same purpose in Ruby. Properly understood, and and or are control flow operators, not boolean operators.

You use them as more like control-flow operators `if`, `unless`. This operations have very [low operator precedence](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence).

Further reading:
[and or and short-curcuit difference](https://avdi.codes/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/)
[short-curcuit](https://blog.revathskumar.com/2013/05/short-circuit-evaluation-in-ruby.html)

Comment: From the example alone it's not clear whether `b` is evaluated. To make it obvious, you could turn `a` and `b` into methods that output something before returning a value – no output, no evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

If you check out sections 11.2.4 *Logical AND expressions* and 11.2.5 *Logical OR expressions* subclause b) of the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html), it is easy to see that evaluation is *left-to-right* and is *lazy in the right operand* (here for example for `||`):

> 1. Evaluate the *expression* or the *operator-OR-expression*. Let *X* be the resulting value.
> 2. If *X* is a falseish object, evaluate the *keyword-NOT-expression* or the *operator-AND-expression*. Let *Y* be the resulting value. The value of the *keyword-OR-expression* or *operator-OR-expression* is *Y*.
> 3. Otherwise, the value of the *keyword-OR-expression* or *operator-OR-expression* is *X*.

You can also see it for yourself:

```ruby
(p('left'); :left) || (p('right'); :right)
# left
#=> :left

(p('left'); :left) || (p('right'); false)
# left
#=> :left

(p('left'); nil)   || (p('right'); :right)
# left
# right
#=> :right

(p('left'); nil)   || (p('right'); false)
# left
# right
#=> false


(p('left'); :left) && (p('right'); :right)
# left
# right
#=> :right

(p('left'); :left) && (p('right'); false)
# left
# right
#=> false

(p('left'); nil)   && (p('right'); :right)
# left
#=> nil

(p('left'); nil)   && (p('right'); false)
# left
#=> nil
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. Unfortunately, the Ruby ISO spec is located behind a paywall (currently ~$200) and is therefore out of reach for many programmers.